# Impact of copula choice on quantiles (sum of random variables)

Tags: probability-distributions, independence, correlation, marginal-distribution, copula

I am trying to get my head around the impact of different dependence structures (copulas) on the risk (quantiles) of a sum of dependent random variables (with arbitrary marginals).

In a multivariate normally distributed setting (Gauss copula + Gauss marginals) everything works (for me) intuitively. Increasing the correlation between the variables under joint normality for example also increases the 99% quantile of the sum of the random variables.

However, things become quite unintuitive (for me at least) when deviating from normality (either with the dependence structure or the marginals). For exmaple, if I use a Gauss-Copula on Pareto marginals increasing the dependence results in lower 99% quantiles than for the case with a zero correlation parameter. I am aware that the Gauss Copula is unable to capture tail-dependence but I still find it hard why the uncorrelated case produces higher quantiles than the correlated one. For less heavy-tailed marginals (such as a student-t) the effect is more similar to the Gaussian marginal case.

Any hint on why an increase in dependence of the Gauss copula results in an decrease of (upper-tail) quantiles would be appreciated (and/or good resources with regard to the impact of dependence structures on diversification / risk quantiles).

Thanks / Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ and their sum $S=X+Y$. Then the variance of $S$ is $$Var[S] = Var[X] + Var[Y] + 2Cov(X,Y) = Var[X] + Var[Y] + 2\rho \sqrt{Var[X]}\sqrt{Var[Y]}$$ where $\rho$ is the correlation between $X$ and $Y$. From this you can conclude that increased correlation will lead to increased variance. Put simply, you have discovered that increased variance will not always lead to increased (tail) quantiles.

Actually, this is only incidentally related to $S$ being a sum or the structure of dependence between $X$ and $Y$. The pertinent fact is that only for a few distributions of $S$ there is a tight connection between Variance and tail behaviour. A well known class with this property are the elliptical distributions, normal and student-t among them. For those Variance determines quantiles. See proposition 6.1.3 in [Embrechts, Frey, Mc Neil, "Quantitative Risk Management"](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691166278/quantitative-risk-management) which is the go-to source for these kind of questions.

In general the connection between Variance and tail quantiles is much looser and you have freedom to wiggle both around. I did explain in some detail the connection between Expected Shortfall and Variance in this [answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/57464/minimizing-variance-vs-expected-shortfall-distributions-where-the-difference-i/57851#57851).

For exactly this reason Variance is quite useless or even misleading as a risk measure for non-elliptical distributions. Furthermore, correlation is of very limited use to express dependence in theses cases.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply and thanks a lot for your detailed answer / hints towards other threads + references. I have actually looked into Embrechts et. al in the past but must admit that I forgot some of it (and some math was beyond me / my patience). What I find really surprising though is that for the Gauss Copula the correlation parameter should strenghten the dependence to some extent but for Pareto marginals I found that quantiles over a large range are systematically smaller.

Comment: I still wonder what a general approach could be if I want to minimize risks? Minimize variance + expected shortfall at the same time or find some balance?

Comment: This question is actually something I wanted to look into for quite some time. There is some literature on extreme value theory for portfolios of independent risks showing that you loose the benefit of diversification for very heavy tailed risks (i.e. equally weighted portfolio of identical risky than single risk). I wanted to get a grasp on whether and how this changes with dependence. It seems like moving out of multivariate normal can give you pretty much any effect you can think of..